# Converting the Json string to float

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting the below JSON from a website link. I need to get the key "market_cap_usd" and convert it to float. When I tried it as mentioned in the below code, It does not coming out in numbers properly.

Advice please.

```
{
    "id": "bitcoin", 
    "name": "Bitcoin", 
    "symbol": "BTC", 
    "rank": "1", 
    "price_usd": "2687.17", 
    "price_btc": "1.0", 
    "24h_volume_usd": "1588210000.0",
    "market_cap_usd": "44081040719.0"
    "available_supply": "16404262.0",
    "total_supply": "16404262.0", 
    "percent_change_1h": "0.05", 
    "percent_change_24h": "-2.05", 
    "percent_change_7d": "8.89", 
    "last_updated": "1498103956"
},
```

**Android-Java Code**

```
float  mkt_cap = BigDecimal.valueOf(json_data.getDouble("market_cap_usd")).floatValue();
System.out.println("mkt_cap : "+ mkt_cap);
```

**Output**

```
System.out: mkt_cap : 4.408104E10
```

Comment: looks like a float to me - `String.format("%.2f", floatValue);`

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: You convert it to a float (`floatValue()`) and loose a lot of precision by doing so.

Comment: And why are you doing all these conversions (string-> double->BigDecimal->float)? This does not make sense at all.

Comment: float can't contain your value properly. It is too large for float

Answer (score 0):

Change float to BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal mkt_cap = new BigDecimal("44081040719.0");
System.out.println("mkt_cap : "+ mkt_cap);
```

Output

```
mkt_cap : 44081040719.0
```

Comment: I need to convert it to float. If I get the float value for mkt_cap then again the same issue

Comment: @iappmaker which issue? `4.408104E10` is a perfectly fine float value and a float has only 6-7 digits precision so don't expect more valid digits.

Comment: I am unable move this bigdecimal to a float variable. In other words I need to get the value stored in float which should be read perfect when I display it in print statement

Comment: @iappmaker you can't. A float by design cannot accurately represent 12 decimal digits. You need to use double (15-16 digits) or BigDecimal (unlimited number of digits) for that.

Comment: you can't convert BigDecimal or BigInteger to float.. float can't handle big number.. you need to change to BigDecimal or String to store or display

Answer (score 0):

try keeping it as a double

```
     double  mkt_cap = new BigDecimal (44081040719.0).doubleValue();
     System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", mkt_cap));
```

**output**

44081040719.00